# Отличие между Engineer и Senior

Tags: обсуждение, диалоги-о-работе

Какие личностные и технические качества отличают инженера от сеньора на Ваш взгляд? Что может сеньор, что не может инженер?

Что по вашему мнению определяет сеньора?

**UPD**

Чем тогда отличаются сеньор и лид?

**UPD2**

Я неправильно выразился. Под Engineer  я имел в виду специалист второго уровня, то есть инженер программист\сисадмин

- 1 level - junior dev
- 2 level - Software dev Engineer
- 3 level - Senior Software dev Engineer
- 4 level - Lead Software dev Engineer

А не специальность инженер.

Comment: имхо умение не только решать техническую задачу, но и выяснять зачем она нужна бизнесу и предлагать альтернативные решения.

Comment: Тут http://www.hr.virginia.edu/uploads/documents/media/wwengineeringdesigndrafting.pdf много всего написано.

Comment: Синьор - это программист, который может решить задачу от и до. Инженер - тот кто эту задачу может кроме того выявить и сформулировать.

Comment: Лид ведет весь проект или несколько, может распределять таски, отвечает за принятые  технические решения, больше занимается митингами и бумажками, кодом меньше.

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под Engineer? Software Engineer -  это просто "разработчик ПО". То, что вы называете Сеньером - это Senior Software Engineer - он все так же "разработчик ПО, просто сеньер". Соответственно, отличия нет и быть не может, тк. Senior Software Engineer одновременно и Senior и Engineer. Это вопрос в стиле "в чем разница между зеленым воздушным шариком и надувным воздушным воздушным шариком"

Answer (score 12):

Нет никакого общепринятого определения Senior Developer. И быть не может.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разделение на Junior/Middle/Senior/Lead появилось из-за необходимости выравнивать ЗП в крупных конторах.

Представьте, что у вас работает 200 разработчиков. И приходит к вам (начальнику) разработчик Паша и говорит "поднимите мне зп на 300 баксов!".

Сказать ему "нет, не поднимем" - нельзя. Поднять просто так - тоже нельзя. Единственный вариант - придумать какие-то "уровни" разработчиков, и привязать к каждому уровню вилку зарплаты. Этим вы убиваете сразу двух зайцев:

- Паше теперь можно сказать "ну ты же уже уперся в верхнюю планку по ЗП для миддла, хочешь больше, становись сеньером и бери на себя вот такие-то обязанности [показывается утвержденный в компании список обязанностей сеньера]".
- ЗП по разным отделам теперь более-менее равномерна, и разработчики не начинают ругаться, когда узнают что такой же "человек уровня миддла" зарабатывает в соседнем отделе в 3 раза больше.

Что обычно обычно включают в список обязанностей Senior? Все, что угодно работодателю. Список обычно подгоняется под текущие реалии компании, т.к. цель списка - не в реальной оценке уровня сотрудника, а в сдерживании роста ЗП.

---

Система достаточно старая, и, по сути, представляет собой обычную тарифную сетку и разряды, но разбавленную заимствованной терминологией. В качестве примера можете посмотреть [Единую Тарифную Сетку Республики Беларусь](http://pravo.levonevsky.org/bazaby11/republic62/text601.htm) (была обязательно для применения в нашей стране до 2011-го года):

5. Специалисты с высшим образ.
   5.1.    - без категории - Junior
   5.2.    - II категории - Middle
   5.3.    - I категории - Senior
   5.4.    - ведущий специалист - Lead

Смотрите в такую сетку - и сразу понятно, что Senior получает от `3,63*База ЗП` до `4,39*База ЗП`. Хочет получить больше? Значит должен идти в лиды, выполнять то, что в документах конторы написано в обязанностях лида, и сможет получать до `4,83*База ЗП`.

В последнее время стало модным заменять разряды/уровни [всякими SMART-целями](https://habrahabr.ru/post/315924/), но суть от этого не меняется - это просто способ контролировать просьбы сотрудников о подъеме ЗП.

Comment: Да, подобная система была всегда, только должности в разных отраслях (и в разное время) именовали по разному. Например, *инженер* - *старший инженер* - *ведущий инженер* - *Главный инженер* (но это уже 1 такой на предприятии и вообще, он уже не инженер, а руководящий работник). Или в НИИ: *младший научный сотрудник (мнс)* - *научный сотрудник (нс)* - *старший научный сотрудник (снс)* - ... (в некоторых, насколько помню, были и *ведущие* и *главные* (*гнс* -))) ... - зам. директора по науке.

Comment: Кстати, в некоторых НИИ инженерные и научные должности существовали параллельно.

Comment: Pasha, вот ты создал свою компанию и решил нанять сотрудников разных уровней . как ты будешь определить какого уровня человек на собеседовании? Что он должен знать и уметь, чтобы конкретно у тебя смог устроиться backend dev?

Comment: Мне казалось, в последнее время модно внедрять плоскую структуру, когда все как бы равны, но ЗП обсуждается индивидуально.

Comment: @Nofate да, и тогда ЗП начинают привязывать к smart-целям и и прочей псевдонауке :(

Comment: @SeniorAutomator для того и существует собеседование. Я при собеседовании обращаю внимание на то, насколько человеку хотелось разбираться в тех проектах, которые он делал. Лез в глубь, копал - хорошо. Просто клепал формочки и хочет продолжать из клепать - плохо.

Answer (score 1):

> на Ваш взгляд

На мой взгляд лид - это руководитель одного заказа. Он может выполнять роль рядового разработчика в других заказах, но в "своём" заказе он ставит приоритеты задачам, транслирует ТЗ разработчикам.

Сеньор - это просто программист высокого класса. Человек, которого персонально пытаются заполучить hr'ы профильных компаний в качестве ведущего программиста. У него может не быть дополнительных скилов и обязанностей, зато он может объяснить "как это работает" себе и другим, знает нюансы языка и обладает навыками нативно-понятного кодинга.

Инженер - это специалист с более комплексным подходом, чем программирование. Он ведёт расчёт (выводит формулы и закономерности) для проекта.

Comment: я имел в виду инженер программист, есть вторая ступень по карьерной лестнице после джуна

Comment: @SeniorAutomator не разделяю вашу градацию. Инженер — это не ступень в карьерной лестнице. Это профессия и образ мышления,  гораздо более широкое понятие. Разработчик — инженер, тестировщик — инженер, сисадмин — инженер, самолёты проектирует тоже инженер. А менеджер — не инженер, хахаха! ))

Comment: У нас в проектах нужны расчеты, хотя на выходе получаются веб-приложения, вот расчетами занимаются инженеры, они и программируют. И на самом деле я впервые слышу, что можно после "Джуна" (кем бы он ни был записан) занять должность инженера-программиста. Обычно меняется категория или добавляется слово "ведущий" при повышении.

Answer (score 0):

Сеньор - это должность. Инженер - это профессия по диплому.

Сеньором может быть кто угодно. Это никак не связано ни с образованием, ни со специальностью, ни с квалификацией.

Карьера, а занимаемые должности в том числе и получаемая зарплата относятся к понятию карьеры, перпендикулярна вашей квалификации. Главное в карьере - это стараться быть угодным вышестоящему начальству. Если попадешь в немилость, то на этом карьера может быть завершена.

Кстати сказать, именно поэтому нередко высококвалифицированные специалисты находятся без работы, так как специалисты по самому определению понятия специалист имеют собственное мнение, а карьеристы не имеют собственного мнения, а имеют мнение вышестоящего начальника. Высококвалифицированный специалист только своим присутствием ставит под сомнение занимаемую должность и получаемую зарплату карьериста. Поэтому высококвалифицированных специалистов терпят по необходимости.

Что касается профессии инженера, то главной чертой должно быть стремление к углубленному изучению предмета и области деятельности. Поэтому чаще всего хорошим инженерам не до карьеры.

Примером типичного инженера является создатель Linux Линус Торвальдс, который не делал карьеру, или создатель языка C++ Страуструп, который также не делал карьеру, а работает преподавателем в учебном заведении.

Comment: да тут несколько статьей можно найти (максимум наскрести) xD

Comment: https://cdn.meme.am/cache/instances/folder411/48892411.jpg

Comment: Всё-таки у нас не платформа для политических дебатов. Предлагаю убрать политические аспекты из ответа. Без них получилось лаконично и убедительно.